# putting divider/line for dropdown in _settings.scss in Foundation

Tags: drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation

Yesterday, I was playing with the _settings.scss fille and I accidentally added a divider(a one pixel line) in between the values of a dropdown. Today, I can't figure it out where it is.

Answer (score 0):

Just decided to write a new class using border-top